# close a window and continue execution in the other one?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I'm really lost...I open a window with two buttons, and when you click on the button called "REGISTER SOME KEY PRESSES" it runs the script called registerSomeKeyPresses.py, BUUUUT once finished I want to close that execution but keep the first window displaying...it's being impossible for me....

Please, i would reaaaally appreciate any help...

Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from Tkinter import *
import threading

v0 = Tk()

def finishApplication(): v0.destroy()
def registerSomeKeyPresses(): 
t = threading.Thread(target=execfile("registerSomeKeyPresses.py"))

t.start()

def waitAndRun(f): v0.after(200, f)

b1=Button(v0,text="TERMINAR APLICACION",command=lambda: finishApplication()).pack()

button_keyPresses=Button(v0,text="REGISTER SOME KEY PRESSES",command=lambda:             waitAndRun(registerSomeKeyPresses())).pack()

v0.mainloop()
```

================ registerSomeKeyPresses.py ===========================

```
Do several things and last command: 

io.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 1**

A second try as a response to your comment:

```
from Tkinter import *
from subprocess import call
import sys

t = Tk()
def click():
    t.iconify()
    try:
        call([sys.executable, 'script.py'])
    finally:
        t.deiconify() # if it should close do t.quit() and t.destroy()
b = Button(t, command= click)
b.pack()

t.mainloop()
```

**Old Version**

What does that do?

================ registerSomeKeyPresses.py ===========================

```
v0.quit()
v0.destroy()
io.mainloop()
```

An other error is:

```
threading.Thread(target=execfile, args = ("registerSomeKeyPresses.py",))
```

if you really neeed a thread.
Do never mix tkinter mainloop things with threads. Threads can use `event_generate` - thats safe.

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for the feedback, the thing is that I know clearly what I want to do but I don't know how to implement it, that's why I might be misusing thread/tkinter...

What I want to do: 

1) display a window with buttons. Every time yo click on a button a call to an external .py is done
2) the external .py is executed displaying all the screen. 
3) Once that .py is finished I want to go back to the window with buttons. 

---Step3 I don't know how to do it ---

Thanks!

Comment: You could refine your question. That would help others, too.

Answer (score 0):

When you destroy the instance of `Tk`, your programm will (and should) exit. If you want to create and destroy windows, create and destroy an instance of `Toplevel` while keeping the main window active. If you don't want to see the main window you can hide it.

Also, tkinter and threads don't mix very well. You cannot call any methods on any widgets from another thread. I've heard other people say you can call event_generate from another thread, but I think that's the *only* tkinter function you can call from another thread.

Comment: This was discussed here: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2013-November/thread.html

Comment: Hi!
it seems that with Tk and an instance of Toplevel I could do this, right?

3) Once that .py is finished I want to go back to the window with buttons. 

---Step3 I don't know how to do it ---

I tried to do it in this way, but I'm going to give it a try again. 

Thanks!

Comment: @Marie: you must have exactly one instance of Tk, and you shouldn't destroy it until you are ready for your program to exit. Once you have that, if you want windows to appear and disappear, use instances of Toplevel.